# Upgrading Win 8.1 to win 8.1 enterprise, USB boot

Tags: windows, boot, uefi, oem, windows-8.1-upgrade

I know that Win 8.1 (Basic Pack) cannot be upgraded to Win 8.1 enterprise directly, by "**add features to 8.1**". I have the 8.1 enterprise image (ISO) and my very own product key.

Here is the problem:

My laptop is a Lenovo Manufactured. The win 8.1(x64 basic pack-single language pack) is pre-installed OEM-UEFI in it. Seems that the basic pack product key is in BIOS and the hard disk has a hidden partition where the OS backup is stored.

Now I bought Win 8.1 enterprise key. I have plan to buy new desktop machine and I am going to install the enterprise OS into it. Until I buy a new machine, I want the enterprise os to run in my laptop.

I want to install it either by USB boot/DVD or through directly mounting the image and installing the setup, without cleaning the OEM setup or cleaning the hidden partition, so that I can restore anytime to basic pack.

I have searched the solution, but can't find out. Help needed! Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no upgrade path from retail versions of Windows to Volume Licensed editions. The only way you are going to "upgrade" is to perform a clean install.

Comment: Shall I proceed with setup double click and install?

Comment: @ManojMaximum did you even read my answer? **There is no upgrade path**